# swift: not identical to ‘UIPickerView’

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I tried the following method which works in Obj-C, but I got error in swift: 
**'(@lvalue UIPickerView!, titleForRow: Int, forComponent: Int) -> $T7' is not identical to ‘UIPickerView’**

```
  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
    {
        var pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        pickerLabel.text = pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: row, forComponent: component)
        return pickerLabel
    }
```

here is the obj-c working codes:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel* pickerLabel = (UILabel*)view;

    if (!pickerLabel){

        pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold Italic" size:25]];

    }

    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

   pickerLabel.text=[self pickerView:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];

    return pickerLabel;

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

   if (component == 0){

               if ([unitType isEqualToString:@"MS"]) {

            return [thickness objectAtIndex:row];

        }else{

            NSString *th = [thickness objectAtIndex:row];

            float tt = [th floatValue]*0.039370078740157;

            NSString *new_th = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.2f",tt];

            return new_th;

        }



    }

   if(component ==1){

        if ([unitType isEqualToString:@"MS"]) {

            return [weight_data objectAtIndex:row];

        }else{

            NSString *wei = [weight_data objectAtIndex:row];

            float ww = [wei floatValue]*2.205;

            NSString *new_wei = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.1f",ww];

            return new_wei;

        }

}
```

Comment: What is return time of pickerView() method which having 3 parameters

Comment: Please show you full code ..

Comment: pickerLabel.text=[self pickerView:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];
 full code is showed. use the above to get the right data again, since the data may need to calculate again.

Comment: show the whole Swift implementation of the method that creates the title.

Comment: `pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)` 
`pickerView(_:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:)` 
`pickerView(_:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:)`  the three above can also show the pickerview content, but should not use them at the same time, I somehow use two of them. Now only using the last one and problem solved.   Thanks all. BTW, it really works with obj-c, so I think swift does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to print the data from which index is selected from `UIPickerView`,But I think you are doing this wrong way.

here is the couple of example for you:

```
    var states : [String]!
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int,
    forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
        var lab : UILabel
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            lab = label
            println("reusing label")
        } else {
            lab = MyLabel()
            println("making new label")
        }
        // You can set text this way where states is an array of string.
        lab.text = self.states[row]
        lab.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        lab.sizeToFit()
        return lab
       }
}
```

refernce from [HERE](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p568pickerView/ch25p842pickerView/ViewController.swift)

Another example is :

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    var pickerLabel = view as UILabel!
    if view == nil {  //if no label there yet
        pickerLabel = UILabel()
        //color the label's background
        let hue = CGFloat(row)/CGFloat(pickerData.count)
        pickerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    let titleData = pickerData[row]
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 26.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])
    
    //This way you can set text for your label.
    pickerLabel!.attributedText = myTitle

    return pickerLabel

}
```

reference from [HERE](http://makeapppie.com/tag/uipickerview-swift/).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I need to use     [self pickerView:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component]     get the recalculated title data again

Comment: I follow the reference you gave, and found the reason.  
Thx.